# how to monitor web searches in android studio from other application

Tags: java, android

I want to make android application that prevents children entering to harmful sites (just like this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qustodio.qustodioapp&hl=en). For this, my application should know web searches in the smartphone (from chrome, firefox, etc...). Anyone knows how to do it in android studio? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve using AccessibilityManager. This will help you to monitor all activity in Android device. E.g click/browsing etc.

Reference Link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManager.html